# Keycloak reset user password via REST API by hash

Tags: rest, change-password, keycloak

The CredentialRepresentation used in the Keycloak 'reset-password' REST API contains fields for hashing algorithm, hashed password, hashing iterations etc.
This implicates that I can pass through a hashed password and all its hashing specifications, instead of passing the plain-text password to the service. This is exactly what I'd like to do, because passing a plain-text password doesn't feel right.

When I try to call the service without the plain-text value however, I get a 400 error with the error message that the plain-text value is missing. Is there any way to pass just the hashed password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in a plaintext password (via HTTPS of course) allows keycloak to hash it using the hash algorithm policy of the realm.

If you want to pass in the hashed password value, iterations and algorithm then you also need to provide the hashing SPI that implements PasswordHashProviderFactory and PasswordHashProvider. And I don't think this is available via the reset-password API, but would work with the Update User API (I haven't tested this).

Rather than specifying a new password manually a better security practice is to use the `PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email` admin call  with `"UPDATE_PASSWORD"` as the required action. This causes Keycloak to send an email to the user that gives a link to set a new password directly.

Comment: Hi, I try using `execute-actions-email` but keycloak return me error 401 Unauthorized. It's my query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221915/keycloak-send-email-reset-password-401-unauthorized-or-500-internal-server-error