# Keycloak send email reset password 401 Unauthorized or 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, keycloak, guzzle

Hi I have a problem with send email to reset password. I using Keycloak 4.8. In [documencation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html) I found:

> Send a update account email to the user An email contains a link the user can click to perform a set of required actions.

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email
```

And **required** params:
`id`, `realm` and `actions`.

I write method using Guzzle:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('put', 'https://myserwerkeycloak.com/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/users/a98e...00d1/execute-actions-email', [
        'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            json_encode([
                'actions' => ['UPDATE_PASSWORD'],
            ])
        ]
    ]);
```

`$response` return 401 Unauthorized

So I added token:

```
'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
```

No I have error 500:

> local.ERROR: Server error: `PUT
>   https://myserwerkeycloak.pl/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/users/a98e...00d1/execute-actions-email`
>   resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response
>   {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException(code:
>   500): Server error: `PUT
>   https://myserwerkeycloak.pl/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/users/a98e...00d1/execute-actions-email`
>   resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\project\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113)

But whe I wont generate `$access_token` I need using email and password, so it's not good resolve because I click 'forgot password, send email...'

**How I can used `execute-actions-email` without authorization ?**